# Does C# implicitly allocate an empty string when a non-empty string is declared?

Tags: c#, string, memory

I'm concerned with a comment on a previous answer that dates back to 2011: [Immutable strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6921113/860585).

It's claimed there that this code

```
string str="a";
str +="b";
str +="c";
str +="d";
str +="e";

console.write(str) //output: abcde
```

creates 10 strings in memory:

```
"", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "ab", "abc", "abcd", and "abcde"
```

While I can get why this happens, I still can't grasp why there is a "" string in the first place. Can someone hint me on this? Maybe that's even not the case? 
C# documentation doesn't shed any light on the issue. 
My only guess here is that C#'s string is a ref type, so it's `null` by default, but like...in this example it gets a value at the very beginning, so I'm kinda perplexed.

Comment: I cant see any reason why an empty string `""` would get allocated

Comment: Where did the information come from that "" will be created in the process?

Comment: Link to the actual answer. In the comments the claim is actually stated, though not explained: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6921113/860585

Comment: the assumption about the 10 string icluding `""` is in a comment without any proof. I wonder whether this can be taken for granted

Comment: Yeah, I'm very suspicious of a 7-year-old comment with no citations. Basing a question on such a comment is not a great idea IMO.

Comment: I suspect that they are talking about the presence of 10 string references in memory not the fact that the first reference is an empty string. The first reference is the declaration itself of the str variable, then there are the 5 constants and finally the four string concat producing the final string.

Comment: @Steve that makes sense, but it's not what the comment says, hence the confusion. :)

Comment: String.Empty is pre-defined and likely to show up in any diagnostic tool that lists "strings in memory".  It does not get used in this code.

Comment: I guess you should contact @nekno and have a chat with him/her about the comment ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is: No, it doesn't.

If you decompile the code generated for a release build you'll see something like this:

```
private static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(string.Concat(string.Concat(string.Concat("a", "b"), "c"), "d"), "e"));
}
```

The IL generated for this code is:

```
IL_0000: ldstr "a"
IL_0005: ldstr "b"
IL_000a: call string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string,  string)
IL_000f: ldstr "c"
IL_0014: call string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string,  string)
IL_0019: ldstr "d"
IL_001e: call string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string,  string)
IL_0023: ldstr "e"
IL_0028: call string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string,  string)
IL_002d: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
IL_0032: ret
```

As you can see, there is no use of an empty string there.

(The code generated is slightly different for a debug build, in order to better support the debugger, but it still doesn't create an empty string.)