# C# how to replace string values. Unable to change even after creating new string variable

Tags: c#

I understand that `string` is immutable, to better understand it I am manipulating it but I am not getting a expected result.
Here is the problem:

Requirments:
Given: string stringToUpdate= 'abcd'.

1. A function should replace the first char of str to its last chars. So char a would be replace by d. And outcome should be dbcd.
2. Also Replace the last char from the first char of str. Then outcome should be 'dbca'.

In simple words replace the string first and last char from each other.

Expected Output: dbca.
But the result is abca.

The result I am getting is  abca, which is wrong, so I am trying to understand why the change happened only for the last char but not for the first char.

Note: I do have other soltuion but I want to understand what is going wrong in the below code.

```cs
public void StringReplace()
{  
    var stringToUpdate = "abcd";

    char firstString = '\0';
    char lastString = '\0';
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= stringToUpdate.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            firstString = stringToUpdate[0];
        }
    
        if (i == stringToUpdate.Length - 1)
        {
            lastString = stringToUpdate[i];
        }
    }
    
    var newString = stringToUpdate.Replace(firstString, lastString);
    //newString after assignment is dbcd, so the change did take place

    var finalString = newString.Replace(lastString, firstString);
    Console.WriteLine(finalString);
   
}
```

**Update**

I was making a mistake, the Replace() method replaces the matching char with other char(s) no matter where they located in the string. Some what I was thiking I am passing the index location and a char to Replace() method. So the way I am using Replace() method it won't give me the expected result. I found other soltuion as follow:

```
var newString= stringToUpdate.Remove(0, 1) 
.Insert(0,lastString.ToString()); var 
finalChange=newString.Remove(newString.Length-1,1) 
.Insert(newString.Length-1,firstString.ToString());
```

Comment: What is your expected output? What do you want `finalString` to be?

Comment: I am trying to understand what are you asking. Is the code not commented working as you wish or not? Do you want to use the commented code but you need an explanation?

Comment: That is a [wonderful `for` loop](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111227-00/?p=8793) you have there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if strings are immutable in c#, how come I am doing this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921097/if-strings-are-immutable-in-c-how-come-i-am-doing-this)

Comment: `it the change but reverted the previous change` - no, it didn't. The original was `abcd`, you arrived at `abca`, which is not `abcd`. Irrespective to that, it is not really clear what you are asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you’ve written does exactly this.

`firstString` is `a` and `lastString` is `d`.

After this line:

`var newString = stringToUpdate.Replace(firstString, lastString)`

`newString` is `dbcd` as the `a`s are replaced with `d`s.

You then call:

`var finalString = newString.Replace(lastString, firstString);`

This will replace all `d`s (`lastString`) in `newString` to `a`s (`firstString`).

This turns `dbcd` into `abca`.

This will give you the output of `abca`, as that's exactly what you've asked for.

It doesn't matter that you have assigned the value to a new string; you're calling `.Replace` on `newString`.

What do you really want?

Comment: Thanks,  for the guidence. I know now, the issue is not in the code, the Replace() is the wrong soltuion for the problem.  Some what I was thinking I am passing the index, surely i wasn't passing the index to Replace() method.  Replace() takes a char to be replace by char.  I am going to answer my question.

Answer (score -1):

The string is reverted because you did it. First you've changed the firstString(which is a char) with lastString(also char of course). But then you revert the parameters assigning the change to final string.

Comment: The final string is nor reverted. It's different from the initial value. And the OP **reversed** the parameters - he didn't "revert" them.